# Arrange custom views in SwiftUI without space or overlap

Tags: swift, swiftui, custom-view

I'm trying to build a UI (SwiftUI / iOS) out of a number of custom views.
All those custom views have a defined aspect ratio or ratio for their frame.

Here's a simplified version of such a custom view:

```
    struct TestView: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.width / 3)
            }
        }
    }
```

My ContentView currently looks like that:

```
    struct TestContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader {geomerty in
                VStack {
                    TestView()
                    TestView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to have the two rectangles to be positioned right below each other (at the top of the screen). So without any space between them. So a bit like an old-fashioned UITableView with only to rows.

But whatever I try, I only get one of two results:

- They are equally spread out over the screen (vertically)
- They overlap (= the view on the top only gets a vertical size of 20

The only solution I've found so far is to define the frame size of the sub-views also in the `TestContentView()`. But that seems to be quite un-SwiftUI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the `GeometryReader` from your content view, since it isn't doing anything
2. You said that your `TestView` has a defined aspect ratio, but, in fact, it doesn't -- it just has a defined width. If you *do* define an aspect ratio, it starts working as expected:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .aspectRatio(3, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct TestContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TestView()
            TestView()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The GeometryReader is needed (in my more complex version of the custom view), but the aspectRatio did the trick. I had tried aspectRatio before, but obviously put it inside the GeometryReader. Now it's a modifier of the GeometryReader and it works like a charm.